# expected an indented block error when making discord bot in python

Tags: python

I was making a discord bot in Python, and when i wanted to run it - the error occurred - expected an indented block, I'll show some code :

I tried to move some things but it didn't work. Also I'm completely new to Python and I have done some things with the tutorials on YouTube. Help me please.

```
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('?help'))
    print('Bot jest online.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(586513031765426198)

    if message.content.find("?ping") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Pong! Jestem gotowy do użytku!")

    if message.content.find("?plany") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Mam zamiar dodać do bota dużo komend!")

    if message.content == "?rzut-monetą":
        variable = [
            'Orzeł!',
            'Reszka!',]
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(variable))

    if message.content == "?pomoc":
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Komendy!", description="Znajdziecie tutaj wszystkie komendy.", colour=discord.Colour.red())
        embed.add_field(name="!ping", value="Sprawdza, czy bot jest teraz online.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="!info", value="Daje informacje o bocie.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="!plany", value="Pokazuje plany na przyszłość dotyczące bota.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="!pomoc", value="Pokazuje tą wiadomość.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="!rzut-monetą", value="Losuje pomiędzy orłem a reszką. Świetne do rozstrzygania sporów.", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)

        if message.content == "?info":
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Informacje!", description="Krótkie info o bocie.", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(name="Autor", value="Pomi ;3#2203", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="O bocie", value="Zadanie tego bota to głównie rozrywka, ale ma też wbudowanego auto-moderatora do polskich przekleństw.", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

one line under the ?info command the first embed is showing on a red background. What could this mean?

Comment: Whitespace matters in Python - double-check your indentation.

Comment: The `if` statement checking for `?info` isn't indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an indented block on the last if

Where you have:

```py
...
        if message.content == "?info":
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Informacje!", description="Krótkie info o bocie.", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(name="Autor", value="Pomi ;3#2203", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="O bocie", value="Zadanie tego bota to głównie rozrywka, ale ma też wbudowanego auto-moderatora do polskich przekleństw.", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Replace with:

```py
...
        if message.content == "?info":
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Informacje!", description="Krótkie info o bocie.", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
            embed.add_field(name="Autor", value="Pomi ;3#2203", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="O bocie", value="Zadanie tego bota to głównie rozrywka, ale ma też wbudowanego auto-moderatora do polskich przekleństw.", inline=False)
            await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

*Note. If you intended to execute only part of that block, unindent whatever you don't care about the condition.*